# Devstack multi node installion

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, devstack

I'm going through the multi-node installation [tutorial](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/guides/multinode-lab.html) and I get errors when trying to configure the Worker Node:

```
 +lib/lvm:_create_lvm_volume_group:114      sudo vgcreate stack-volumes-lvmdriver-1 /dev/loop1
  Physical volume '/dev/loop1' is already in volume group 'stack-volumes-lvmdriver-1'
  Unable to add physical volume '/dev/loop1' to volume group 'stack-volumes-lvmdriver-1'
  /dev/loop1: physical volume not initialized.

....

nova-compute: no process found
neutron-openvswitch-agent: no process found
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:524          exit 1
```

Here is my config file:

```
HOST_IP=192.168.122.129
FIXED_RANGE=10.4.128.0/20
FLOATING_RANGE=129.168.122.128/25
LOGFILE=/opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log
ADMIN_PASSWORD=asti
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
DATABASE_TYPE=mysql
SERVICE_HOST=192.168.122.129
MYSQL_HOST=$SERVICE_HOST
RABBIT_HOST=$SERVICE_HOST
GLANCE_HOSTPORT=$SERVICE_HOST:9292
ENABLED_SERVICES=n-cpu,q-agt,c-vol,placement-client
NOVA_VNC_ENABLED=True
NOVNCPROXY_URL="http://$SERVICE_HOST:6080/vnc_lite.html"
VNCSERVER_LISTEN=$HOST_IP
VNCSERVER_PROXYCLIENT_ADDRESS=$VNCSERVER_LISTEN
```

So the **first** question is what's the problems seems to be?

I gave my machine 4096 RAM and 1 CPU (it's suppose to be a small compute node).

**Second**,what are the `HOST_IP` and `SERVICE_HOST` suppose to mean? Do they point to this machine or the Controller Node?

**Furthermore**, [in the example](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/guides/multinode-lab.html#network-configuration) the the `FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.42.128/25` but the IP are `192.168.42.11` which fall outside of the range.

Here is how I set the IP on this worker node:

```
stack@ubuntu:~/devstack$ cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      addresses:
        - 192.168.122.129/24
      gateway4: 192.168.122.1
```

And the output of `ip addr`:

```
stack@ubuntu:~/devstack$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:db:93:79 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.129/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.122.162/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global secondary dynamic enp1s0
       valid_lft 3200sec preferred_lft 3200sec
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fedb:9379/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ovs-system: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 62:49:cc:69:9f:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: br-int: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8a:b9:bb:9b:25:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br-ex: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9a:4e:18:d5:0a:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: br-tun: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 96:05:5d:7d:b2:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:85:0f:94 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.123.1/24 brd 192.168.123.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:85:0f:94 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Answer (score 2):

SERVICE_HOST is the Control Node IP

You are getting the error because you set the SERVICE_HOST and HOST to same host IP.

also, once nodes are up run this from the devstack directory on Control node:

```
./tools/discover_hosts.sh
```